# Performance hit in ActiveMQ

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms

Is there a noticeable performance hit in doing the following in a Spring based application:

```
Destination destination;
destination = new ActiveMQQueue(someFunctionArgumentString);
```

I am concerned that this will not be going through connection pooling and any other caching that Spring will have in place to manage destinations. As such, what is the preferred approach to sending a message to a destination under AMQ?

Answer (score 2):

The destination object has nothing to do with connection pooling; it just configures the queue/topic.

Wrap the AMQ connection factory in a `CachingConnectionFactory`; it will use a single connection and cache consumers/producers when using the `JmsTemplate`.