# How to use Spring's JmsTemplate with a connection pool?

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-jms

As far as I know Spring's `JmsTemplate` with the default configuration uses a synchronous approach to send messages which makes the performance really bad. Is there any way to use connection pool here?

```java
public void insertIntoMQ(String kafkaMessage) {
    //log.info("Inside insertIntoMQ function");
    try {
        jMSConfiguration2.insertIntoMQ(kafkaMessage); 
        log.info("Message Inserted Successfully :\n" + kafkaMessage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception Inserting Message Into MQ ", e);
    }
}
```

the above method calls the below `insertIntoMQ` method in different class to insert message.

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class JMSConfiguration2 {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    
    private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger log = org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
            .getLogger(JMSConfiguration2.class);

    @Value("${ibm.mq.queueName}")
    private String queueName;
    
    @Async
    public void insertIntoMQ(String kafkaMessage) {
        //log.info("Inside insertIntoMQ function");
        try{
                    
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, kafkaMessage); 
            log.info("Message Inserted Successfully :\n" + kafkaMessage);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            log.error("Exception Inserting Message Into MQ ", e);
        }
    }   
}
```

I have added caching connection factory, but performance is somewhat better but not upto the mark . ***i'm able to achieve 320 TPS but I need bit more TPS . As far as I observed , only 8 threads/8task running at any point of time to insert message to MQ but there are loads of message waiting to be inserted but only 8 threads getting created to insert . so , anyway to increase that?***

```java
@Configuration
public class MQutil {

    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        try{
            System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false");
            // Create an MQConnectionFactory with the MQ properties
            MQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory = new MQConnectionFactory();
            mqConnectionFactory.setHostName(".ca");
            mqConnectionFactory.setPort(1414);
            mqConnectionFactory.setQueueManager("TQMGR");
            mqConnectionFactory.setChannel("CHANNEL");
            mqConnectionFactory.setSSLCipherSuite("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256");
            mqConnectionFactory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);

            UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter connectionFactoryAdapter=new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter();
            connectionFactoryAdapter.setTargetConnectionFactory(mqConnectionFactory);
            connectionFactoryAdapter.setUsername("e");
            connectionFactoryAdapter.setPassword("es");

            cachingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory(connectionFactoryAdapter);
            cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(10);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Exception Inserting Message Into MQ "+ e);
        }
        return cachingConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory());
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName("TEST.TOPIC.QUEUE2");
        return jmsTemplate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With minor tweaks I was able to speed up your code about **~400 times** within my environment. Your code is slow as it is paying many costs:

- cost of opening connection on each call
- cost of creation of jms session
- cost of opening queue
- cost of message persistence within transaction

There are also some other costs like creating JMS MessageProducer, but they are not as dominant. In my environment code like yours is able to publish about **22-23 msg/sec**.

If you use spring CachingConnectionFactory with default settings, it will cache both connection and session. In my environment code like this is able to publish about **400 msg/sec**. Be aware - you cannot use CachingConnectionFactory within application container. In that case, grab connectionFactory from JNDI and the connection cache will be provided by app container.

For next step, you can set QoS attributes to NON_PERSISTEN and acknowledge mode set  to AUTO_ACKNOWLEDE. These steps additionally boost message producing speed to about **750 msg/sec** in my environment.

For final boost of speed you need to tweak destination settings on MQ destination. Set **Default put response type** property to *Asynchronous*. Under MQSC console this property is known as **DEFPRESP** on your Queue; or you can set it trough MQ Explorer:

[image: DEFPRESP property]

With this final change, I was able to push **~8500 msg/sec** in my environment.

All this performance boost comes from:

- resource caching
- sending, flushing and acknowledging buffers; and not individual messages. Essentially the way how Kafka does it.

The alternative approach is also possible by using JMSTemplate's [executes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html#execute(java.lang.String,org.springframework.jms.core.ProducerCallback)) methods, as you can control many finer scope/caching details within Session or ProducerCallbacks.

Some disclaimers:
In IBM MQ, non persistent messages are still persisted to disk, however acknowledge is returned to sender when message is stored to a memory buffer, and not when the buffer (and message) is flushed. This means that in unexpected power loss you will lose unflushed messages.

Some other tweaks are possible on MQ server level, however that is well beyond Java, Spring and JMS.

This is code example with all optimizations enabled:

```
void sendItFast() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false");

    MQConnectionFactory cf = new MQConnectionFactory();
    cf.setHostName("ca");
    cf.setPort(1414);
    cf.setQueueManager("ESB");
    cf.setChannel("CHANNEL");
    cf.setSSLCipherSuite("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256");
    cf.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);

    CachingConnectionFactory ccf = new CachingConnectionFactory(cf);
    ccf.afterPropertiesSet();

    QosSettings qosSettings = new QosSettings();
    qosSettings.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

    JmsTemplate jt = new JmsTemplate(ccf);
    jt.setExplicitQosEnabled(true);
    jt.setQosSettings(qosSettings);
    jt.setSessionTransacted(false);
    jt.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(JMSContext.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    jt.afterPropertiesSet();


    int msgCount = 20000;
    String message = "Hello world: ";

    long duration = - System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (int i = 0; i < msgCount; i++) {
        String payload = message + System.nanoTime();
        jt.convertAndSend("SPEED_TEST", payload);
    }

    duration += System.currentTimeMillis();
    float speed = msgCount * 1000 / duration;
    System.out.println("Sent " + msgCount + " in " + duration + " ms. " + speed  + " msg/sec");
}
```

Comment: @Talijianac, thanks for the info .. I tweaked my CachingSession factory . now , i'm able to insert message at ~840 TPS but as far as know if there is no load then open/alive threads sessions should close automatically after 60 secs but in my case the threads are alive forever connected to MQ and not closing/dying . could you help?

Comment: CachingSession factory? I do not know what that is. Spring CachingConnectionFactory will never release connection until factory is closed. Same with Session level caching. Both approaches are valid and present no perf issue, and are actually recommended MQ programing. The only issue with "long-term-session"  is sending lots of messages without sending ack or commit/rollback signal. However you do not have that problem as you are using JmsTemplate which will always send those. If you want some specific override use third party connectionpool like pooled-jms or roll your own. It is nice workout.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CachingConnectionFactory`.

[Performance hit in ActiveMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756054/performance-hit-in-activemq/43760587#43760587)

[JmsTemplate and CachingConnectionFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897687/jmstemplate-and-cachingconnectionfactory/28899869#28899869)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#jdbc-connection-factory-caching

Comment: I have added caching but still same performance . please see my edit above

Comment: That template isn't a `@Bean` so something else is being `@Autowired`. You should make the connection factory and templates beans.

Comment: thanks , I need to increase the TPS now . since , performance is not adequate yet . please find my edit above.